# How to manage response assertion if the values are same but sequence changes in Jmeter

Tags: api, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

I am getting response, let's suppose {"profiles":{"HLS_1200":[{"profile_id":38,"quality_id":11}],"ADAPTIVE" {"L","XL","XXL"}, now every time when we hit the API the response is same but the sequence is getting changed and therefore assetion is getting failed.
Next time I will get the response like {"profiles":{"HLS_1200":[{"profile_id":38,"quality_id":11}],"ADAPTIVE" {"XL","L","XXL"},
I want to pass this response assertion even if the sequence is changed.

Comment: What you want to assert exactly? that you get specific parameters? you can use JSON extractor

Comment: I want to compare the whole respose using response assertion but every time the sequence is getting changed hence response assertion is getting failed.I am doing API automation where I want to compare the response

Answer (score 0):

Go for [JSONAssert](https://github.com/skyscreamer/JSONassert) library which performs "deep scans" and doesn't care about the order of the attributes

1. Obtain the following libraries and drop them to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath):

   - [android-json-0.0.20131108.vaadin1.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/vaadin/external/google/android-json/0.0.20131108.vaadin1/android-json-0.0.20131108.vaadin1.jar)
   - [jsonassert-1.5.0.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/skyscreamer/jsonassert/1.5.0/jsonassert-1.5.0.jar)
2. Restart JMeter to pick up the libraries
3. Add [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) as a child of the request which returns your JSON
4. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def expected = '{\n' +
           '  "profiles": {\n' +
           '    "HLS_1200": [\n' +
           '      {\n' +
           '        "profile_id": 38,\n' +
           '        "quality_id": 11\n' +
           '      }\n' +
           '    ],\n' +
           '    "ADAPTIVE": [\n' +
           '      "L",\n' +
           '      "XL",\n' +
           '      "XXL"\n' +
           '    ]\n' +
           '  }\n' +
           '}'

   org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONAssert.assertEquals(expected, prev.getResponseDataAsString(), false)
   ```

More information:

- [Introduction to JSONassert](https://www.baeldung.com/jsonassert)
- [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri , is there any other way to do it

Comment: What's wrong with this one? There is couple of more listed in [The Easiest Way To Compare REST API Responses Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-easiest-way-to-compare-rest-api-responses-using-jmeter) but they also require either scripting or 3rd-party libraries like [jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial) or both

Comment: Dmitri, here is the response I am getting from server {"status":"success","message":"Asset detail Response","status_code":null,"data":{"asset_id":1023354,"asset_title":"Movie  Name","asset_type":"movie","images":[{"image_id":9003826,"image_type":"horizontal_poster_without_title","image_type_id":2,"cdn_url":"image.jpg","image_title":"imagr.jpg","variants":["s","xl","xs","l","m","thumbnail","xxl"]}, and so on in this everytime I need to exclude variants":["s","xl","xs","l","m","thumbnail","xxl"] this part only in response assertion. What code could be written, Can you please help Dmitri